# window.fbAsyncInit / FB.init does not appear to be running

Tags: authentication, facebook-javascript-sdk, access-token

I am just getting started with the Facebook JavaScript SDK, all I want to do is enable users to log in to my web site with their FB account. First I put in the `<div class="fb-login-button">Login with Facebook</div>` and the boilerplate  just like it says in the Facebook for Websites documentation at developers.facebook.com/docs/guides/web/#login

I click the FB login button, get the popup, click Allow...and nothing happens. I can't find any cookie like fbsr_APPID anywhere (e.g. `Request.Cookies("fbsr_MYAPPID")` turns up nothing) and the page didn't redirect to the Site URL I specified in the App's settings. I put some more JavaScript in to debug, and literally get nothing.

```
window.fbAsyncInit = function () {
    FB.init(
{
    appId: 'MYAPPID',
    channelUrl: http://bla,
    status: true,
    cookie: true,
    xfbml: true,
    oauth: true
});
    // Additional initialization code here
    alert("Please just prove this init code is running at all!!!!");

    FB.Event.subscribe('auth.login', function (response) {
        alert('Logged in: ' + response);
    }
    );

    FB.getLoginStatus(function (response) {
        alert('Check login: ' + response);
        if (response.authResponse) {
            var access_token = response.authResponse.accessToken;
            alert('Access token yay! ' + access_token);
        }
    });
};
```

None of the alerts show up or anything, leading me to think the whole script is failing to run.

I switched from that  facebook button to the server-side authentication link described at developers.facebook.com/docs/authentication, and this time the redirect definitely happens and I get a **code=** in the query parameters, but I get the same [lack of] results running any FB.JavaScript methods, in Init or as an event handler. I still can't find a facebook cookie (tho maybe the server-side method never produces one?) but I figure with an Ajax call or something I'll be able to use the code to get the access_token (it'd be nice if FB's documentation gave some hints on how to *use* that code, but that's another issue).

Even if I ditch Facebook's JavaScript SDK as much as possible and rely on server-side scripting, I ought to be able to at least use FB.getLoginStatus. What could I be doing wrong?

Comment: What errors do you get in your browser's console?

Comment: there was no mention of the required `<div id=fb-root></div>` in your description of your system... is it there? :P

Comment: Oh yeah that <div> is present.

Comment: @DMCS Firefox and IE9 don't show any scripting errors in the status bar or anything.

Comment: Can you code up an example of it on jsfiddle.net and post it here.  Here's a sample of one of mine that works fine.   http://jsfiddle.net/dmcs/qrXkZ/2/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I've narrowed your problem down to this line

`channelUrl: http://bla,`

It should read (of course with a real url to your channel file:

`channelUrl: 'http://bla',`

Comment: Yes that was exactly the issue. More precisely, I wasn't using a literal URL but something more like `channelUrl : <?=channelURL?>,` and assumed that it'd get assigned as a string because I defined the (server-side) variable as a string. Ah no. Once I changed it to `channelUrl : "<?=channelURL?>",` it started working fine. Thanks!